# Consolidating to show the latest non-null value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr2

I have the following schema, with representative sample data added for this question:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d8bcc/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table foo(id integer, att1 varchar(9), att2 varchar(9), from_at date);
insert into foo(id, att1, att2, from_at) values(1, 'J', null, sysdate-5);
insert into foo(id, att1, att2, from_at) values(1, null, 'L', sysdate-4);
insert into foo(id, att1, att2, from_at) values(1, 'B', null, sysdate-3); 
insert into foo(id, att1, att2, from_at) values(1, 'C', null, sysdate-2); 
insert into foo(id, att1, att2, from_at) values(1, null, 'H', sysdate-1); 
insert into foo(id, att1, att2, from_at) values(1, 'A', 'H', sysdate);
insert into foo(id, att1, att2, from_at) values(2, null, 'H', sysdate-1); 
insert into foo(id, att1, att2, from_at) values(2, 'A', null, sysdate);


| ID |   ATT1 |   ATT2 |                         FROM_AT |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |      J | (null) | December, 01 2012 15:13:42+0000 |
|  1 | (null) |      L | December, 02 2012 15:13:42+0000 |
|  1 |      B | (null) | December, 03 2012 15:13:42+0000 |
|  1 |      C | (null) | December, 04 2012 15:13:42+0000 |
|  1 | (null) |      H | December, 05 2012 15:13:42+0000 |
|  1 |      A |      H | December, 06 2012 15:13:42+0000 |
|  2 | (null) |      H | December, 05 2012 15:13:42+0000 |
|  2 |      A | (null) | December, 06 2012 15:13:42+0000 |
```

I'd like to be able to show each row, but substitute `att1` and `att2` for the *latest* value for that `id`. a `null` attribute indicates one that hasn't changed from the previous time a row was inserted, a non-`null` attribute indicates the new value. The output should look like this:

```
| ID |   ATT1 |   ATT2 |
------------------------
|  1 |      J | (null) |
|  1 |      J |      L |
|  1 |      B |      L |
|  1 |      C |      L |
|  1 |      C |      H |
|  1 |      A |      H |
|  2 | (null) |      H |
|  2 |      A |      H |
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with `lag` and `ignore nulls`:

**Query**:

```
select id, 
       nvl(att1,lag(att1 ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by from_at))
         as att1,
       nvl(att2,lag(att2 ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by from_at)) 
         as att2
from foo
```

**Results**:

```
| ID |   ATT1 |   ATT2 |
------------------------
|  1 |      J | (null) |
|  1 |      J |      L |
|  1 |      B |      L |
|  1 |      C |      L |
|  1 |      C |      H |
|  1 |      A |      H |
|  2 | (null) |      H |
|  2 |      A |      H |
```